# Multiple indexers not allowed error, but they are not indexers

Tags: flowtype

My goal is to create an `Entities` type, which is an "exact object type" of all the keys in `K`.

`K` is:

```
type SocialEntity =     Article    | Thumb    | Comment    | Displayname    | Helpful;
type SocialEntityKind = 'articles' | 'thumbs' | 'comments' | 'displaynames' | 'helpfuls';


const K:  {[key: SocialEntityKind]: SocialEntityKind} = { // short for SOCIAL_ENTITY_KIND
    articles: 'articles',
    thumbs: 'thumbs',
    comments: 'comments',
    displaynames: 'displaynames',
    helpfuls: 'helpfuls'
}
```

Now I tried setting `[key: typeof K.*]` but its considering these indexers.

```
type Entities = {|
    [key: typeof K.articles]: {
        [key: ArticleId]: Article
    },
    [key: typeof K.thumbs]: {
        [key: ThumbId]: Thumb
    },
    [key: typeof K.comments]: {
        [key: CommentId]: Comment
    },
    [key: typeof K.displaynames]: {
        [key: DisplaynameId]: Displayname
    },
    [key: typeof K.helpfuls]: {
        [key: HelpfulId]: Helpful
    }
|}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Is there any easy and right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax will not work for what you are trying to do. `[key: TYPE]: TYPE` in Flowtype is syntax for [using objects as dictionaries](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps), not syntax for computed property names.

It is also not possible to use `typeof` in the way you want, because the type is just `string`, not `articles` exactly. You'll have to manually put in the names of the keys.