# Object must NOT have key

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to define that an object must NOT have a certain key.

Here is my case:

```
alert({
   items: [{ label:'Apple' }, { label:'Orange' }]
})


alert({
   items: [{ foo:'Apple' }, { foo:'Orange' }]
   labelKey: 'foo'
})
```

If items is an array of ojects that does not contain "label" key, then labelKey is required in Options

I tried this:

```
type Options = {|
   items: Array<{ label:string }>
|} | {|
   items: Array<$Diff<{}, { label:string }>>,
   labelKey: string // must be key in items
|}

function alert(options: Options) {

}
```

Bonus question:
Also is it possible to define that labelKey is any key from objects passed in items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Ensuring a property does not exist on an object

#### tl;dr: use `{ myProp?: empty }`

I'm assuming you want to use the [objects as maps](https://flow.org/try/#0AQ4FwTwBwU2BZAhlA6gSzACwDKIEYwA2wAvMAN4BQooA2gM5gBOaAdgOYC6AXMIyxwA01GsEL4ivfm3bCaAX0oiQkWAmTosAewCuYXAWJlyDZjJ7AAtmgAeMACaCxEwgH5eMS1EiLl4aHAA8t5oWqz0pBQAPn6gGJ70vACCTEyIEAA8SKgYOC4AfH5R8sBR0bEg4oYA0jAQUmZCFcDxlonAKWmZ2ZqYuvoFcqDFSjT2MADG4kxwAGY6rBNgoazAiIQwTGAAFFohYe3BywcAlLwAblpo9gDco6DrmztUoi1gCby05M6G3ADkSSgUA2f2A8k4QxA8hO9xAjy22xeola7S+P0kAKBILBEOAAHo8cAAKKpLRMYAAWmAAGU+jpCPZgKwtGBgJhEOc4FUiBVuYRavVgH8tJhmX9IWCYX54c9mijPt9ZlotP9AcCYKDwRLQHyBbw-kqtH8-NDYWsNgikcj3m0FcBDaqsRqcU4CcTSeSqQA5GAOCKIdH8uomk7AIA) when you pass something into the `alert` function. The trick to creating a map without a label is to give a property that, if assigned to something, will fail to typecheck.

We can leverage the [`empty` type](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2225), a type which doesn't match against anything, to get the desired effect. It's a little tricky to use an `empty` type in conjunction with an object map, because by defining a property, we tell flow that we *want* that type to be in the object. So this fails to typecheck:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0AQ4FwTwBwU2BZAhlA6gSzACwDKIEYwA2wAvMAN4BQooA2gM5gBOaAdgOYC6AXMIyxwA01GsEL4ivfm3bCaAX0oiQkWAmTosAewCuYXAWJlyDZjJ7AAtmgAeMACaCxEwrxiWokRcvDQ4AeU80LVZ6UgoAHx9QDHd6XgBBJiZECAAeJFQMHBcAPh8I+WAIyOiQcUMAaRgIKTMhMuBYy3jgJJT0zM1MXX08uVBCpRp7GABjcSY4ADMdVjGwYNZgREIYJjAACi0gkNbAxb2ASl4ANy00ewBuYdBV9a2qURBm1tpyYGmtLW4AcgSoFA1r9gPJOANRBUiNVasBfl8tL8fPIjkA))

```
type MapWithLabel = {
  [string]: string,
  label: string,
}

type MapWithoutLabel = {[string]: mixed, label: empty}

type Options = {|
   items: Array<MapWithLabel>
|} | {|
   labelKey: string,
   items: Array<MapWithoutLabel>,
|}

declare function alert(options: Options): void;

alert({
   items: [{ foo:'Apple' }], // Error, expected a "label" property with empty type
   labelKey: 'foo'
})
```

Next, we can define the property as [optional](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-optional-object-type-properties), which means to only typecheck against `empty` if the property exists. With this we can give the object a "label" property that either:

- Does not exist OR
- Has a type that matches nothing (empty)

So code can either not have a value for that property (what we want), or it can pass something that is empty (this isn't possible).

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0AQ4FwTwBwU2BZAhlA6gSzACwDKIEYwA2wAvMAN4BQooA2gM5gBOaAdgOYC6AXMIyxwA01GsEL4ivfm3bCaAX0oiQkWAmTosAewCuYXAWJlyDZjJ7AAtmgAeMACaCxEwgH5eMS1EiLl4aHAA8t5oWqz0pBQAPn6gGJ70vACCTEyIEAA8SKgYOC4AfH5R8sBR0bEg4oYA0jAQUmZCFcDxlonAKWmZ2ZqYuvoFcqDFSjT2MADG4kxwAGY6rBNgoazAiIQwTGAAFFohYe3BywcAlLwAblpo9gDco6DrmztUoi1gCby05M6G3ADkSSgUA2f2A8k4QxA8hO9xAjy22xeola7S+P0kAKBILBEOAAHo8cAAKKpLRMYAAWmAAGU+jpCPZgKwtGBgJhEOc4FUiBVuYRavVgH8tJhmX9IWCYX54c9mijPt9ZlotP9AcCYKDwRLQHyBbw-kqtH8-NDYWsNgikcj3m0FcBDaqsRqcU4CcTSeSqQA5GAOCKIdH8uomk7AIA))

```
type MapWithLabel = {
  [string]: string,
  label: string,
}

type MapWithoutLabel = {[string]: mixed, label?: empty}

type Options = {|
   items: Array<MapWithLabel>
|} | {|
   labelKey: string,
   items: Array<MapWithoutLabel>,
|}

declare function alert(options: Options): void;

alert({
  items: [{ label:'Apple' }],
})

alert({
  items: [{ label:'Apple' }], // Error - Should not have label
  labelKey: 'ohno',
})

alert({
   items: [{ foo:'Apple' }],
   labelKey: 'foo'
})

alert({
   items: [{ foo:'Apple' }], // Error - Needs a labelKey
})
```

So to get the desired effect, we needed to leverage two tools: optional properties and the `empty` type. With it, we can specify an object that will fail to typecheck if that `empty` property exists.

## Setting a dynamic property key at the type level

#### tl;dr: not possible

Regarding the bonus question: I'm not sure Flow could understand that since I don't know of a way to set a variable property on objects. I would not expect this feature since it could make things complicated/impossible to type check.

Edit: After a little more research, you *can* use [indexer properties](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps) to assert an object has a key at the type level:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwOoEtgAsDSEQB4AqAXFAM7ABOKAdgOYB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2vgLrFlKtADQcoAQwByAVwC2cCOWIBmUZ3EAxaVQDGwFAHsqxABQBKJgwBuBlABNRAXzZs7EHQBtx5aFe9RpEggSABlxBQ9ieGQ0LBxcAHIvCIS6FxNA4LCIgDpkiEjSCmoaMwBuNgyg0PCCnKk5BSUoKkbFcsrMmtzZFBISEuJW+XayqAB6cYBRcnIDcigAWigAEQNgqgTgKAgADz7toygDRHdgTursus1tPUNjKHNLKBt7Dqqs2o96rV19IwExVo5Qm01m8yWUCQc1oUFAkDYQA))

```
type ObjWithKey<T: string = 'label'> = {
  // An indexer property with only one valid value: T with "label"
  // as default, but we can't ensure that the property exists anymore
  // and multiple indexers are not supported.
  [T]: string,
  aNumber: 3,
  aFunction: () => void,
}

declare var usesLabel: ObjWithKey<>

(usesLabel.label: string);
(usesLabel.aNumber: number);
(usesLabel.missing: number); //Error - Doesn't exist on object
(usesLabel.aFunction: () => void);
(usesLabel.aFunction: string); //Error - Wrong type
```

However, you can't do that *and* use the object as a general map, since multiple indexer properties are not supported ([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwOoEtgAsDSEQB4AqAXFAM7ABOKAdgOYB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2vgLrFlKtADQcoAQwByAVwC2cCOWIBmUZ3EAxaVQDGwFAHsqxABQBKJgwBuBlABM13QdRr8oslAA8IDqAHo-KABRcnIDcigAWigAWWlgABsUMAToajsIb3ISKDsjAHJgKAB3cIBrKEITNgBfNjYMnQTxcmgrFqhpEggSABlxBQTieGQ0LBxcfObB-Lp6zhMunv7BgDppiCHSChczAG42Re6+gc3VqTkFJSgqS8V9w6WTtY8SEhdiW-l7vf8-ELCEWiABEDD0qIUoJkUGQoEY4YgIHpHscVmdNNo9IZjFBzJYoDZ7A8jstTglzlpdPojAIdrR9n8AeEolAkGFaFBQJA2EA)). For reference, someone else tried to do something else similar, [but couldn't get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255748/multiple-indexers-not-allowed-error-but-they-are-not-indexers).

If that's a major problem for you, see if you can architect your data structure in  a different way to make it easier for static analysis with Flow.

Comment: Oh my gosh this is amazing. Thank you very much James I struggled with this forever doing all kinds of weird things with the utility functions. Thank you very very much!!

Comment: On line 22, I was trying to make it so it is acceptable if it is: `items: [{ label:'Apple', ohno:'hi' }], labelKey: 'ohno' }]`. As long as the `labelKey` is within the object it is no error. I tried to massage the above to get this affect, but couldn't do it. Is this not possible? Basically the requirement is value of `labelKey` must be in each item; and `labelKey` defaults to "label".

Comment: @Noitidart, I get what you're trying to do, but it's tricky. Surprisingly, you _can_ get Flow to understand an object contains a key that you specify at the type level: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwOoEtgAsDSEQB4AqAXFAM7ABOKAdgOYB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2vgLrFlKtADQcoAQwByAVwC2cCOWIBmUZ3EAxaVQDGwFAHsqxABQBKJgwBuBlABNRAXzZs7EHQBtx5aFe9RpEggSABlxBQ9ieGQ0LBxcAHIvCIS6FxNA4LCIgDpkiEjSCmoaMwBuNgyg0PCCnKk5BSUoKkbFcsrMmtzZFBISEuJW+XayqAB6cYBRcnIDcigAWigAEQNgqgTgKAgADz7toygDRHdgTursus1tPUNjKHNLKBt7Dqqs2o96rV19IwExVo5Qm01m8yWUCQc1oUFAkDYQA using a feature called indexer properties.

Comment: @Notidart, However, you can't get it to simultaneously allow you to use the object  as a generic map anymore, since multiple indexer properties are not allowed: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwOoEtgAsDSEQB4AqAXFAM7ABOKAdgOYB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2vgLrFlKtADQcoAQwByAVwC2cCOWIBmUZ3EAxaVQDGwFAHsqxABQBKJgwBuBlABM13QdRr8oslAA8IDqAHo-KABRcnIDcigAWigAWWlgABsUMAToajsIb3ISKDsjAHJgKAB3cIBrKEITNgBfNjYMnQTxcmgrFqhpEggSABlxBQTieGQ0LBxcfObB-Lp6ky6e-sGAOmmIIdIKFzMAbjYF7r6BjZWpOQUlKCoLxT2DxePVjxISF2Ib+Tvd-z8QsIi0QAIgYelRClBMigyFAjLDEBA9A8jstTpptHpDMYoOZLFAbPZ7oclicEmctLp9EYBNtaHtfv9wlEoEgwrQoKBIGwgA

Comment: Thanks so much for this awesome learning. It would be awesome if one day we can do this. Thanks again very much James! Amazing amazing learning from your amazing solution update!!

Comment: Haha thats my old topic :P

Comment: Wow, thanks, this answer deserves much more than 4 points! 